# I search set Column Class for laravel-datatables

Tags: laravel-5, datatables

In my laravel 5.7/ blade / jQuery v3.3.1 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 app

I use "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0" library 
and when I need to change class of some rows depending on value of some field I do :

```
return Datatables
    ::of($votesCollection)
    ->setRowClass(function ($vote) {
        return $vote->status == 'N' ? ' row_new_status' : ($vote->status == 'I' ? 'row_inactive_status' : '');
    })
```

It works ok, but I did not find any similar methods for columns. Are there ? Can it be implemented in some way ?

**UPDATED # 1**:
In my blade file I define header of the table :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-primary" id="get-warehouse-dt-listing-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Level count</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Updated At</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>
```

but not generated rows.
Or can I define it in blade? Please example, if yes.

Thanks!

Comment: Columns are defined in your blade file. You can add any logic you want there.

Comment: Please look at UPDATED # 1

Comment: Can you add an example what element you would want to manipulate? Because columns are made by separate cells and its not very clear from your question.

Comment: Can the decision be some css trick, when setting css class to a whole row, it is applied only for some td columns, say first only?